# Unable to send email from SQL Server with query result

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I used below code to send email from SQL Server 2014 Express.

It works by below code, if I do not have query.

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
     @profile_name = 'SimpleMail',
     @recipients = 'xxxxxx@hotmail.com',  
     @body = 'Quote',
     @subject = 'Sub'
```

It fails, if I add @query.

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
     @profile_name = 'SimpleMail',
     @recipients = 'xxxxxx@hotmail.com',  
     @body = 'Quote',
     @query = 'SELECT Quote.DocNum FROM Quote',
     @subject = 'Sub'
```

Error message is:

> Msg 22050, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
> Failed to initialize sqlcmd library with error number -2147467259.

Query is valid query.

```
SELECT Quote.DocNum FROM Quote
```

Comment: have you tried with `@execute_query_database` parameter to tell it what database that table is in?

Comment: Just add `@query_result_header = 1`.